# Which "Real World" Company was the first to have its' name featured in an actual (numbered) Lego set?

Tags: piece-information, history

Excluding the *Lego* company, which "Real World" Company was the first to have its' name featured in an actual Lego set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 1955 Bedford Esso truck sets that [oddTodd refers to](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/2477/750) were the earliest appearance of a company name/logo on a product in the LEGO system, however these trucks were sold separately as part of the Town Plan, without bricks (although some versions of the [1251 set](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=1251-2) came with 1x1 bricks that were used as oil cans). An [accessory set from 1955](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=1247-2) included gas pumps and a printed Esso sign, but no building elements.

The first regular building set to include a company logo or name was [1310 Esso Filling Station](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=1310-1) from 1956. The next building sets to include a company name and logo were [306 VW Garage](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=306-2) and [307 VW Auto Showroom](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=307-2), both released in 1958. (The first use of the VW logo was on the first 1:87 scale car LEGO produced in 1956, the [VW Bus](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=275-2).)

Usage of the Esso name ended in Europe and Australia in 1965 and in the US in 1966. In 1966 the Shell brand name was first used in set [325 Shell Service Station](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=325-3)

Answer (score 4):

Esso (aka ExxonMobil) showed up in one of the first sets ever, released in 1955. Bedford, a truck maker, was also represented in the same set (and others from that year). I do not know if there were Bedford sets released before the Esso/Bedford sets, since they were all released in the same year.
http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=1250-2

Esso also shows up on an actual printed brick in this 1958 accessory set:
http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=226-1
Note that 1958 was the start of the current stud-and-tube technology.

Ferguson plastic tractor (1951):
http://aboutus.lego.com/en-us/lego-group/the_lego_history/1950